# Image in compositing showing and then disappearing

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I've been following BlenderGuru's Donut video tutorials for Blender 3. I'm up to the [Compositing chapter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlmq6EXzzzw), however I'm stuck at the very beginning, because the compositing backdrop isn't showing:

[image]

After a bit of investigation, I realized that when pressing this icon in the "Render Layers" node, it shows me the rendered frame and then disappears:

[image]

What I've tried:

- I have rendered the frame using F12
- "Use Nodes" is enabled
- Backdrop is enabled
- My "Render Layers" node connects to the Viewer node and Composite node via the "Image" pin
- Removing the connection and then re-adding it to refresh it

So far I have followed these troubleshooting tips, but to no avail:

- [Rendered Image not showing up in compositing tab](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192454/rendered-image-not-showing-up-in-compositing-tab)
- [Backdrop doesn´t work/ image won´t show up (for compositing)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71481/backdrop-doesn%C2%B4t-work-image-won%C2%B4t-show-up-for-compositing)
- [Backdrop not available in Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55990/backdrop-not-available-in-nodes)

You can see my .blend file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sEqBlFsaz_LkZzNvnBHo9FpmBuyRrYfu/view?usp=sharing)

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Output panel > Post Processing*, you've enabled the *Sequencer* option, and you have a video strip in your *Video Sequencer* editor, so it will try to render the strip, not your scene. So either disable the option or remove the strip. In my opinion it's better to manage the videos in another blend file, you'll avoid this kind of problem. Also you can activate the *Backdrop* option of your Compositor if you want to see your render as background.

[image]

Comment: That solved it, thank you!

Comment: did not help :( please see my comment added with details on my same issue. would appreacite your ideas!

Comment: Please don't use the Your Answer field to ask a question, instead click on Ask Question, also please share your file so that we can check